# Virtual CMFCListCtrl select same item after sorting

Tags: mfc

I am using CMFCListCtrl with LVS_OWNERDATA.

After sorting I want to select the item with same data

for e.g

In this list control 3rd item is selected.
[image: Before Sorting]

Now I sorted the first column by header clicking, now the selected item is 3rd row.But I want to select the item based on data for.e.g before sorting the selected item has label value as "startup" and the address as "0x00000060". I want to select the item by data not by index.

[image: After Sorting]

You can get sample application for virtual list control with sorting from this link https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/listview/advanced/article.php/c4151/MFC-Virtual-List-Control.htm

Please help me to achieve my requirement.

Comment: Save the selection, sort the list, find the old item and select it. Also call `CListCtrl::EnsureVisible` on the old item.

Comment: `SetItemData` and `GetItemData`

Comment: @sergiol You can't use `SetItemData` and `GetItemData` for virtual list control